# Hadoop fsck shows missing replicas

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, fsck

I am running Hadoop 2.2.0 cluster with two datanodes and one namenode. When I try checking the system using hadoop fsck command on namenode or any of the datanodes, I get the following:

```
Target Replicas is 3 but found 2 replica(s).
```

I tried changing the configuration in `hdfs-site.xml` (dfs.replication to 2 ) and restarted the cluster services. On running `hadoop fsck /` it is still showing the same status:

```
Target Replicas is 3 but found 2 replica(s).
```

Please clarify, is this a caching issue or a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting `dfs.replication` does not bring down your replication. this property will be referred only when a files is created whose replication is not specified. For changing the replication following hadoop utility could be used

`hadoop fs -setrep [-R] [-w] <rep> <path/file>`

or

`hdfs dfs -setrep [-R] [-w] <rep> <path/file>`

Here **/** also can be specified for changing the replication factor of the complete filesystem.

Comment: I have transferred files to HDFS without specifying the replication factor and at that time the replication factor was set to 3 but i have changed the replication factor to 2 afterwards. Then i am getting this Target Replicas is 3 but found 2 replica(s).

Comment: hadoop fs -setrep [-R] [-w] <numReplicas> <path>
is the full command also
hdfs dfs -setrep [-R] [-w] <numReplicas> <path>
will work. Details - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#setrep

Comment: Thanks, missed out fs